# What is the difference between gcc option -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE and kernel configuration CONFIG_FORTIFY_SOURCE

Tags: security, gcc, kernel, fortify-source

I want to confirm the difference between gcc option -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE and kernel configuration CONFIG_FORTIFY_SOURCE. As far as I could understand, gcc option -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE is for compile time checks where out of bounds check is done for str and mem functions. Kernel configuration CONFIG_FORTIFY_SOURCE=y is for run time checks where at run time, kernel code checks for out of bounds errors. Is this correct understanding ?

Comment: Both these things are for **compile**-time checks. Setting the macro `_FORTIFY_SOURCE` enables these checks when str-related functions in **glibc** are called. Enabling configuration `CONFIG_FORTIFY_SOURCE` enables these checks when str-related **Linux kernel** functions are used. (Linux kernel doesn't use glibc, so setting the macro `_FORTIFY_SOURCE` in the kernel code is useless.)